# Can`t resolve image.png in styles.css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Webpack cant build the project, because cant resolve image.

Project structure

```
project/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ assets/
│  │  ├─ images/
│  │  ├─ styles/
├─ package.json
├─ webpack.config.js
```

Here is webpack.config.js

```
{
  test: /\.(JPG|gif|svg|gif|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    filename: 'assets/images/[name].[contenthash:7][ext]'
  },
  use: [{loader: 'url-loader'}]
},
```

and main.css

```
.b-promo {
  background: url(../assets/images/bg.png) top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
```

Error message

```
ERROR in ./assets/css/main.css
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../assets/images/bg.png' in '/home/path/to/project/src/assets/css'
```

Comment: The path to image from CSS file is not correct. Check exact path once

Comment: so I will just write a relative path from CSS file to image?

Comment: `Error: Can't resolve '../assets/images/bg.png' in '/home/path/to/project/src/assets/css'` where is that **css** folder it can't find ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like url() should take a string as a parameter [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()#values)

So try in main.css (and make sure that the relative path to bg.png file from main.css one is correct):

```css
.b-promo {
  background: url("../assets/images/bg.png") top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Nope. even with quotes does not work. same error "cant resolve"

Comment: @Edward maybe the problem in the relative path? Shouldn't it be just "../images/bg.png"?

Comment: Also, take a look at your CSS code: don't forget to add a semicolon after a background-size property (that's not the solution for the current problem, but may cause other problems)